# Static content on Angular 2 app HTML page

Tags: html, angular

I am designing and developing a new application where front end is Angular2 and backend is spring boot. Angular2 and spring boot will communicate on REST in JSON format where backend will provide all dynamic details.However, I am looking what's the best possible way to serve the text content on HTML to an Angular2 in a flexible way rather than hardcoding content on HTML pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With JSON Object**

You can simply save the static texts in JSON object and do the CRUD operations locally.

**With an API Endpoint**

You can invest more time and create a set of APIs that serve the static contents. This gives you a possibility to manage them through a CMS too.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of more about the CMS so the content can be managed by business and change dynamically without need of DB. Do you have any further insight on the CMS solution?

Comment: What you can do is to create a simple database table to keep your static data, let's say a page. You can create an API end point to serve the content and by /v1/pages endpoint you can get your pages list and with /v1/pages/:id you can get a content of a specific page.